# how to create dynamic filter in text area of spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I want to create a dropdown in text area to filter data in table dynamically.

I have many entries under Filter "Task Description".

But I want to create a dropdown in text area with only below three entries out of all entries.

- All - it will show the entire data
- Prasanta - this selection will only show Prasanta related rows
- Chandan - this selection should only show Chandan related rows.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

the best and simplest way to do this is with a **Text Area** visualization containing a **Property Control**. I'll give you a loose outline and you can use the [Spotfire help on Property Controls](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/text/text_details_on_property_control.htm) to get more detail.

1. add a new **Property Control** of type **Drop-down list** to a **Text Area**
2. create a new **Document Property** of type string
3. set the property value through Expressions
4. the expressions you list here should evaluate to boolean true or false. for example, for Prasanta rows you might use `[Task Description] = "Prasanta"`. the expression for All rows should be blank.
5. on the **Data** page of the filtered visualization's Properties, scroll down to **Limit data using expression** and click Edit...
6. from the middle pane, double click the name of the **Document Property** you created in step 2 above
7. test by selecting different items from the dropdown you created